# AWS - Application Load Balancer with HTTPS to ECS container not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecs, aws-elb

I've setup an ECS Cluster running a single container as is. The container configuration has host port set to 0 to make use of dynamic port mapping. I've checked and all the network related setup is correct.

If I hit the IP of the EC2 instance directly with the dynamic port assigned to it (e.g. 54.555.555.54:33424) I get the login screen as I expect.

I've configured the Application Load Balancer to use HTTPS with a single listener port on 443 (Target group points to port 80 on the container side). The ELB has the certificate to use with my domain, which I got from ACM.

When I hit the default URL of the ELB, I can't reach the container. I did a curl on the URL and saw that it was a certificate issue, which makes sense since the default URL is not the URL associated with the ACM certificate. However when I hit the custom URL, which is setup with the ARM certificate, I get connection refused.

I did a curl on the custom URL and I actually get a result in the terminal. It shows a redirecting message. Which is the same message I get if I were to curl the IP:Port.

I've checked and my container is healthy on both the ECS side and the ELB side, so it's passing health checks.

Anyone has any idea what the heck is going on here? Any specific Task/Container settings I have to enable to get dynamic port mapping or HTTPS working?

Any help would be awesome, I've been at this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

you should create A record for custom domain name with your elb in route53 service